# Is there a way to disable or 'soften' the visual effects of validation errors at the initial state?

Tags: wpf, validation, user-interface

What I have so far is: A WPF application, using MVVM, IDataErrorInfo implemented. Everything is working as expected.

Every time I open a "Create New Entity" dialog, the user is saluted with a nice form, flashing red all over the place. This is expected in a pure validation point of view, but it is annoying and I would like to be able to do either one of two thing.

1. "Soften" the red error highlighting color to lets say orange, or yellow, to indicate "Required field". Subsequently, when the user starts interacting with the controls switch to the red highlighting
2. If that's not possible, is there a way to disable error highlighting @ initial state?

I found this post [How can I get WPF to NOT display validation errors upon initial display of control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821998/how-can-i-get-wpf-to-not-display-validation-errors-upon-initial-display-of-contro) dealing with the same problem, but it is not really answered.

I considered implementing a "Clear All error" within my IDataErrorInfo implementation, as well as implementing an InitialState flag, so errors wont be added until at least one field was changed by the user, but those have side-effects.

1. If I clear all errors after init, the validation is off, but the submit button is, of course, enabled :(
2. If I use an InitialState flag, which is also bound to the submit button to disable it... I get one step further, but then ALL errors are added with the change in one single property field.

So before I go and add InitState flags for EACH property, I though I stop and ask if there might be a simpler, more generic solution to this.

I can post some code if required. However, I implement the IDataErrorInfo in a standard way, a `Dictionary<string,string>` for the error messages, the Property Fields with OnChange Events and a switch case statement to call individual validation methods.

EDIT:
Here is what I ended up with.

1. I added an `IsInitState=true` flag for each 'Required' field property in the VM
2. In the setter code this flag is set to false on first change

   ```
           if (Name != value)
           {
               Name = value;
               IsInitState_Name = false; 
               base.OnPropertyChanged("Name");
           }
   ```
3. In the ValidateName (), the Null/empty test is conditional based on the flag

   if (!IsInitState_Name && String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Name))
4. Submit button "canExecute" checks if all flags are == false before enabling submit
5. It's some extra work, but only needed for "required / non-null able" properties. Now the Create new interface is initially without error messages yet validation is fully functional

Comment: I selected Dan Bryant answer as accepted because it pointed me into the right direction. At the end, I used parts of all three answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to not consider the initial 'empty' state to be invalid (thus not causing the UI to reflect an error), but to do a separate set of checks (including non-empty) before allowing a Commit.  In this case, you can set an error for each property that was 'empty' when the Commit was attempted.  One consequence of this is that making a box empty by editing the text will clear any error on the box, but that may not be too terrible.

Comment: Hi Dan, I'm not sure I understand completely what you say. But reading your answer made me realize I do not need to turn of validation at all, just temp. disable the "empty/null" validation rules. They are the once responsible for firing right away. That way, the user still gets notified if entering a wrong value ... nice, one step closer, thanx

Answer (score 2):

You could add a flag to your class that flags if the class should bypass it's validation or not.

For example, when a class is newly created have the `ShouldValidate` flag default to false. If the new class already exists, such as pulling it's data from the database, set the `ShouldValidate` flag to `true`. When the user executes the `Save` command, set `ShouldValidate` to true if it is false.

If your class also has an `IsValid` property then set the `ShouldValidate` to true prior to running your Validation code, since usually if you're calling `IsValid` you are usually expecting the control's validation to run (most of my validating classes have this property, and I usually check IsValid before saving)

Comment: Thank you Rachel,  If I understand you correctly, this is what I tried to say with using an "InitialState" flag. I could, as you suggest validate all input at the end, prior to submit. But, my real goal is to avoid a bulk validation. The user should be notified while at the input field if there is a mistake, not at the end.  I think I can achieve this by implementing what you say on a property level, not class level. Add `ShouldValidate` to each property ... I guess I have to go ahead and do just that   Thanx

Answer (score 0):

here's a ControlTemplate I use with a less harsh red color, and a tooltip to display validation error messages; sample is for a ComboBox but it's the same for TextBox etc:

```
  <ControlTemplate x:Key="ValidationErrorTemplate" TargetType="Control">
    <DockPanel>
      <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" Opacity="0.3" CornerRadius="3">
        <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
      </Border>
    </DockPanel>
  </ControlTemplate>

  <Style x:Key="ValidatableComboBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="ToolTip" 
           Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self},
                   Path=(AutomationProperties.HelpText)}" />
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate"
            Value="{StaticResource ValidationErrorTemplate}"/>
  </Style>
```

And applied:

```
  <ComboBox Style="{StaticResource ValidatableComboBoxStyle}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=...}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding Path=..., ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
                           UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            AutomationProperties.HelpText="Click to select a valid item."/>
```

I have no answer for the other part of your question though, but the above was too long for a comment so I made it into an aswer anyway..

Comment: Thanx for taking the time stijn. Maybe I didn't made this clear, but I do like to keep my red validation for normal use. I'm looking to have it slightly changed for the initial state.  However, looking at your Control template gave me a new idea: would it be possible to have two validation templates, and switch them?